"Mister" followed by first name
I was talking to a customer support representative who had an Indian accent. She kept referring to me as "Mister Barry" (Barry is my first name).
Is most of the English-speaking world, we generally only use honorifics like "Mister" before last names. The incongruity of the formal honorific combined with the informal first name was quite jarring to me.
I don't think this is the first time I've encountered this. Is this a common form of address in Indian English? I'm surprised they don't train CSRs in the vernacular of other countries when dealing with those customers.
I know there are some contexts where we use this type of naming in the US, but they almost always involve people we're close to. Preschool children may refer to their teachers this way ("Miss Alice"), children call their pediatricians "Dr. firstname" (I think this reduces anxiety), and in some communities (esp. the South) it's common for some elders of the community (women, in particular) to go by nicknames in this style. But it seems out of context to use it when talking to a total stranger.

It's quite common in the U.S. Southeast (and even up to the mid-Atlantic). My wife (a New England native) was taken aback when she moved to Maryland and heard herself addressed that way: Miss Firstname.. by children of friends and acquaintances.

As with my exception, that's from children. Do adults talk to each other that way?

@Barmar at a railway station in India I was greeted by someone who asked "Are you Mister Peter?" Naturally, I said "Yes" and he replied "Well come, please let me take you to your hotel." (As it turned out, he had met the wrong person :)

@WeatherVane Did he really split "Welcome" into two words? Was it actually "Well, come, please let me..."? :)

@Barmar you can't tell from the way they say it, but they often write it like that. I observe that Barry is not an unusual surname, but Peters is more common than Peter.

@WeatherVane She had my account information, so I think she should have known which is my surname.

I meant that it is reasonably certain that he was addressing me by my firstname.

@PaulTanenbaum's example can also be found in the US southeast when an adult addresses another adult, especially of a higher social class.

@phoog Good point, like when the slaves referred to "Miss Scarlet" in Gone with the Wind. But that feels very dated to me. I wonder if it persists in India due to the caste system.

@Barmar in my experience it is still actively in use in North Carolina and Virginia, at least, as well as (25 years ago) at my (minority-owned) employer in Philadelphia (as you're probably aware, certain elements of southern culture persist in the descendants of the great migration).

@Barmar your upvoted comment about splitting 'welcome' is a red herring. I was actually, in India, addressed by my first name like that, so perhaps the customer support representative was trying to be friendly / polite.

I also found it offputting that she said "Mr. Barry" in practically every sentence. Americans don't address each other by name so much.

I'm sure the "Mister" is out of respect, but "Mister surname" is how we normally address someone respectfully.

As I mentioned in my updated question, that use in the South is usually reserved for people you're familar with.

An Indian friend mentioned that they had only one name, and when they had to produce a surname, used a parent’s name instead. I don’t know how prevalent this is in India, but this system would fit the Mr Firstname pattern since Mr Lastname would be their father. I’ve also noticed this among Chinese in Malaysia, though not in Singapore. Here, it might have to do with the order of names, with surname traditionally appearing first, followed by given names. Likewise in Japan with Firstname san and their surname-first name ordering.

It's mentioned in answers to this closed question, and for other places this and this

@Barmar, Miss Firstname sometimes has the purpose of making it clear who is addressed or referred to in a setting in which there is more than one unmarried woman of the same surname. That is something very different from Mister Barry. (The readers of Jane Austen's novels are familiar with the convention of addressing the eldest daughter of the family as Miss Surname and her sisters as Miss Firstname; that convention was followed by people of the same social status as the family, not only the servants.)

@jsw29 That's reminiscent of the way the slaves in Gone With the Wind referred to Miss Scarlett.

@Barmar, I was in fact responding to your comment about Miss Scarlett, above. My point was that the reason for that form of address may have been independent of the class relations.

Oops, didn't look back to see that I'd already said that. I definitely wasn't aware of the practice you describe of distinguishing the siblings (I've never read Austen).

I was about to downvote that Question but wait a minute, please. Sorry, and 'Most of the English-speaking world…' pretty-much does mean India.
Can we all please remember at last census, India had a population of 1.4 billion, against about 8 billion on Earth, a huge percentage of whom spoke English simply because their own mother tongues wouldn't work in the next town…
Meanwhile the entire English-speaking population of Earth was perhaps 2 billion…
That says India is right and you and I are in the global minority.
I still vote for British English, and so what?

@RobbieGoodwin While India may have a larger population, English is not the national language and most Indians don't speak it. There are more English speakers in the US than India. Wikipedia

Sorry, Barmar… your argument is not with me but with Google in particular and the interweb in general.
Of course English isn't the 'national language' of India but I suggest any useful research will show English is the most widely used language in the sub-continent… just as it will show you there might be more students of English in China than there are speakers in US America.

@RobbieGoodwin Google AI claimed 30% of Indians speak English, but I think most other sources say about 15%. I'll believe Wikipedia over AI.

And regardless of the number, to virtually all Indians English is a second language. They don't define the English-speaking world.

I, too, would doubt AI against most other sources and the idea that only 30% of Indians use English seems to me risible. Still like yourn, other views are available.
If you need another example, have you tried using French in Europe?


Is this a common form of address in Indian English?

Yes. It is used to show a certain deference without being overly formal. I, like others, have experienced it on the Indian Subcontinent and elsewhere (China, Africa, The Caribbean.)

This may sometimes happen due to language trasfer. When immigrants from another language overcrowd a place , some of their native langauge features may widley spread. In Persian, for example, it is quite common to use "Mister" before the first name and even "Miss" or "Mrs" (regardless of the marital status) precedes the first name.
